# Creating charts in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to create chart out of two columns. The first one contains only two distinct values (it's sex, male or female) and the second one contains numbers from one to five. I want to put those numbers on the X coordinate and to see how many males and females have chosen each number. So on the Y coordinate should be numbers 1 to 544 (increment by 50 for example; 544 is last number because  that's how many rows I have in table).
It should look something like this [image]

What my question is, can I do this only by inserting chart and selecting the fields I need or I must use some functions first to summarize result set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you don't need to do some bigger research, and if you are new to Excel like I am, and trying to find an easy way to create charts from your data you should use Pivot table.
It's easy to use, just by dragging columns you can set what is going to be on which coordinate.